# Inventory issues in The Pit

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I am constantly, constantly running out of inventory space. I like to craft with my engineer and I'm on floor 28 so I'm pretty far down there. I'll probably play again with a Marine. Can someone give me some pointers that I may have missed about inventory management? What's useful, what isn't?

I do look up recipes so typically there is something I'm waiting to build, but the game is evil and gives me too many of one thing and never enough of another. I spent 5 levels hauling nothing but rifle ammo but no food and then another five levels fully fed with nothing but raw meat and no ammo.

Furthermore, I can't seem to selective pick things up off the ground. Any hints on inventory management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To selectively pick things off the ground hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>g</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For inventory management, the first tip is to try and increase your Might. Every 10 points of Might increases your inventory space by 6 slots. That's the only reliable, controllable way to increase inventory space. Secondly, if you have the DLC, start with one of the characters that starts with a utility belt (Tarkan, Liir, Morriggi). Equipping it will also increase your inventory space. Even if you don't like that character, you can run them 5 floors to the next locker room and deposit for a character you do like. Next, try and save up the parts for a Lifter Pack, and build it asap. It doesn't take up an equipment slot, only takes one inventory slot, and when used adds 12 inventory slots. Finally, there's the randomly dropped Pocket Tesseract, which also increases inventory space.

As for what is useful and what isn't, that really depends on the playthrough you're doing. A spare weapon/armour, plenty of ammo, food, and medicine are always useful,  but outside of that it depends on what skills you've boosted (what weapon skills you've focused on, which utility skills you've got) and what other items you have. For example, if you've found no energy cells or backpacks, have low Might / inventory space, or haven't invested in the Rifle skill, then holding onto parts for laser weaponry isn't the best idea, as most use the Rifle skill, energy backpacks tend to take up a lot of inventory space, and they are generally high ammo consumers. If you're not using Psi Powers, then holding on to Psi Boosters or Pineal Glands doesn't have much point. Things like that, that are really subjective based on the playthrough and can't be predicted in advance.

I didn't know about selectively picking things up with Ctrl + G before reading the other answer, but that's a really useful thing to know.